# Python Input Varible

Tags: python-3.x

```
test = input( 'PRINT ')
if test == 'QUIT' :
    quit()
else :
    print('FAILURE')
```

If I type QUIT My code work perfectly but if I leave a space after typing QUIT I get failure how do I make input allow Spaces after typing QUIT?

I need a way to do this with out importing any modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `strip` function for `strings` trims all whitespace (spaces and tabs) from both ends of the invoked variable.

```
test = input('PRINT').strip()

if test == 'QUIT':
    quit()
else:
    print('FAILURE')
```

Comment: Great if only I could only allow spaces and end please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test = input( 'PRINT')
if "QUIT" in test:
    quit()
else :
    print('FAILURE')
```